# laravel jetstream installation

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

started a laravel project and keep coming across this error during installation.

(base) Sergios-MacBook-Pro:basic yeyo$ composer require laravel/jetstream

[UnexpectedValueException]
Invalid version string "^8.0"

require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] []...

(base) Sergios-MacBook-Pro:basic yeyo$

I'm not sure how to fix this. Any advice will help thanks.

Comment: do have installed composer package?

Comment: yes i do.    Sergios-MacBook-Pro:basic yeyo$ composer --version
  Composer version 2.1.12 2021-11-09 16:02:04
  (base) Sergios-MacBook-Pro:basic yeyo$ composer require laravel/jetstream

                                 
  [UnexpectedValueException]     
  Invalid version string "^8.0"

Comment: Please provide more information about what you tried so far. Are you running the command in a laravel project? Try composer update and than the require command

Answer (score 0):

you can try running the command:

```
composer global update 

composer require laravel/jetstream
```

Comment: still not working         composer global update 
Changed current directory to /Users/yeyo/.composer
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /Users/yeyo/.composer
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file. See https://getcomposer.org/basic-usage
-- also tried composer self-update and it did not work

Comment: Is it a new project? As the error is: Invalid version string "^8.0"! which version of laravel you are using?

Comment: I'm using the newest version of laravel.    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "platform-check": true,
        "platform": {
            "php": "^8.0"
        }.       ---- saying that the config.platform.php invalid but it's the latest version of php